# Хранение html страниц в базе данных

Tags: php, html, mysql, веб-программирование

Занимаюсь разработкой новостного сайта и появился вопрос, на который не могу найти однозначный ответ.
Есть сайт на котором будут размещаться несколько видов новостей. Эти новости редакторы будут сами собирать при помощи самодельного "конструктора" на сайте и после того, как новости собраны они должны отображаться на главной странице в блоках начиная самой последней новости.
По моему плану, новость, после того как ее создали, записывается в базу данных. А точнее не новость, а ее заголовок, заглавная картинка и ссылка на созданный файл.

Возникает проблема с отображением этих новостей для разных пользователей. Дело в том, что у обычного юзера и у админа на сайте будут разные кнопки в меню на каждой странице. Получается в идеале нужно брать разное меню в зависимости от того, какой пользователь зашёл, добавлять к нему html код ранее созданной новости и показывать ее пользователю.
Получается, что в базе данных нужно хранить не ссылки на новости, а html код страницы без html кода меню.
Есть ли в этом смысл и на сколько это правильно и безопасно?

Возможно, я очень плохо передал суть. Могу постараться перефразировать если нужно.

Comment: в базе данных нужно хранить id новости, ее заголовок, дату публикации, краткий текст, полный текст, id юзера кто ее добавил. Сведения о прикрепленных изображениях в том или ином виде. Все что относится к меню и т.п. к БД вообще отношения чаще всего не имеет. Но прежде чем начать  разрабатывать новостные сайты, возьмите и почитайте литературу о вэб разработке.

Comment: @teran тем не менее остается проблема: как открыть новость с главной страницы. Вставить ссылку на нее саму, которую храним в базе данных?

Comment: если у вас стоит тэг php, то очевидно ссылка должна вести на php-скрипт, которому нужно передать идентификатор новости. скрипт генерит шапку и подвал страницы. а так же вытаскивает контент новости из БД.

Comment: @teran получается, что контент новости это и есть html код. На сайте 4 разных вида новостей с разной версткой и стилями. Значит все таки html код нужно хранить в базе данных в условном поле "контент"?

Comment: да, но в вопросе вы туда включали еще и всякие меню, чего делать не стоит. Более того, вам нужно хранить этот самый тип новости, и частично вопрос стилей и т.п. можно решить на уровне вывода данных, а не хранения.